# Difference between an adviser and supervisor

Tags: word-choice

As far as I know, an adviser is the one who offers an advice.

A supervisor is the one who makes sure things are done correctly.

In a media channel a person who checks things at ***the final stage*** to make sure that nothing is aired that contradicts the policy, or shouldn't be aired due any factor, is called **an adviser or supervisor?**

Why this question revolves in my mind because I saw somewhere the word '**adviser**' being used for ***a person on the job I've mentioned***. I think: an advice can be turned down. But whatever the man on this job says is accepted; i.e. cutting the video, editing, blurring, etc. None of his words is rejected since he is the authority and *is* responsible too.

Do I have the right position that this person shouldn't be called 'an adviser'?

Answer (score 2):

As per Cambridge dictionary

> A **supervisor** is *"a person who is in charge of a group of people or an area of work and who makes sure that the work is done correctly and according to the rules."*
>
> An **adviser** is *"someone whose job is to give advice about something, for example, to a company or government."*

But there is no rule that says an adviser (or advisor) cannot enforce a rule. Sometimes, "adviser" forms a part of the title of a position that holds supreme power and authority.

Such a person will have a strong command over his staff. In your case, it cannot be said with certainty, because what the organization calls this person (adviser/supervisor) depends completely on their rules and regulations.

---

Edit: There are many positions in a newsroom. I will use this as an example, every "media channel" may have their own setting or style of operation. [Who Works in a Television Newsroom?](https://www.thebalancecareers.com/tv-news-careers-525690) provides detailed descriptions of all the people involved in important aspects of the operation. To know more, take a look at [How the newsroom works](https://www.ourcommunity.com.au/marketing/marketing_article.jsp?articleId=1607).

> **Producer** - Producers oversee newscasts. The executive producer coordinates every aspect including hiring, firing, and managing personnel and also tending to business and financial matters. At larger stations, associate producers assist executive producers, and together they supervise a staff of news producers. A producer writes scripts, edits video, and collaborates with reporters who are out in the field. He or she also works closely with the newscast's anchor.
>
> **Director** - News directors plan news broadcasts. They choose and schedule content, making them the people most responsible for what viewers see on the air.
>   The news director is in charge of quality control. He or she monitors stories for accuracy and sees that rules and regulations are followed.

Source: [Who Works in a Television Newsroom?](https://www.thebalancecareers.com/tv-news-careers-525690)

Comment: @ AIQ Actually I want to know what a person is called whose job is to check the content on final stage before a programme is aired?

Comment: @xeesid Take a look at my edit.

Comment: All very interesting, but anyone who has worked in a large organisation, such as a media channel, knows that the words used in job titles do not always, (I would say, rarely) reflect the normal meaning of those words in other contexts. They might or might not reflect some aspect of the job done in the past by someone with that kind of job title, but, if so, that is a coincidence. I once held the job title of 'Assistant Secretary'. No amount of citing of dictionaries would tell you that that was quite an important job.

Comment: So the job title 'advisor' might mean some person who gives advice but is not actually responsible for anything, but might in practice be the most important and influential person in the organisation. Whereas a 'supervisor' might be the person who checks that the junior clerks get into work on time. When I was an Assistant Secretary one of my subordinates was a 'Senior Chief Executive Officer'. Don't go on job titles alone.

Comment: @JeremyC That is exactly what I wrote in my answer. *"But there is no rule that says an adviser (or advisor) cannot enforce a rule. Sometimes, "adviser" forms a part of the title of a position that holds supreme power and authority."* But OP wanted specific titles (i.e., the position that has certain authority as per the books or literal definitions). But you phrased it wonderfully. Can I incorporate your comment in my answer with proper credit?